# I am stuck in this question..proof by induction divisibility

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

> Prove using induction : $3^{2n} + 4^{n + 1 }$ is divisible by $5$  for $n ≥ 0$.

I solved all the questions and still this one only remains unsolved.
Has anyone got an idea?

Comment: Show your attempts. What did you try?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What have you tried? Is it true for $n=0,n=1$? Then note that $3^{2(n+1)}+4^{n+2}=4(3^{2n}+4^{n+1})+5\cdot3^{2n}.$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $f(n)=3^{2n}+4^{n+1},$

Eliminate one of them

$$f(m+1)-f(m)=3^{2m}(3^2-4)$$ which is divisible by $5$

Or $$f(m+1)-9f(m)=4^n(4-9)$$ which is divisible by $5$

So, if $5$ divides $f(m),5$ must divide $f(m+1)$

Comment: Thank you so much for ur reply

Answer (score 0):

For $n=0$, we have $5|1+4$. Now, let's assume $5|3^{2k}+4^{k+1}$, then

$$
3^{2(k+1)}+4^{(k+1)+1}=3^{2k}\cdot9+4\cdot 4^{k+1}=4(3^{2k}+4^{k+1})+5\cdot3^{2k}\equiv0\pmod 5
$$

By the principle of mathematical induction, we conclude $5|3^{2n}+4^{k+1}$ for all non-negative integer $n$.

Comment: Thank you so much for ur reply

Answer (score 0):

Step 1

for $n=0$ and $n=1$, it is a multiple of 5

Step 2

Assume for $n=k$

$3^{2k} + 4^{k + 1 }=5t, t\in Z$ (is divisible by $5$).

for $n=k+1$

$3^{2k+2} + 4^{k + 2 }=  9\times3^{2k} + 4\times4^{k + 1} +5\times 4^{k+1}-5\times 4^{k+1}=9(3^{2k} + 4^{k + 1})-5\times 4^{k+1}=9\times 5t-5\times4^{k+1}=5(9t-4^{k+1})$

Hence it is a multiple of five

Comment: Thank you so much for ur reply